# MS Azure - Publish server address

Tags: azure

Hi I am signed up with Azure (Free Trial) at the moment and when I am trying to publish my application the connection to the Azure server failed where can I find my azure server address to publish to?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the official guides first. There's a pretty good explanation on how to publish your application to Azure. Assuming you're using App Service, [here is the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2019) you need. The publish profile contains all the information you need to access the host server.